# How can Itachi use his Mangekyō Sharingan after death?

Tags: naruto

When Naruto was forced to fight Itachi for the first time when he was reanimated by Edo Tensei, you could clearly see that he could still use the power of his Mangekyō Sharingan. How is this possible if Itachi no longer had his original eyes (which Sasuke took it)? Does this mean that Edo Tensei can also restore certain aspects of a ninja even after death?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can reanimated bodies get their eyes back?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5745/how-can-reanimated-bodies-get-their-eyes-back/5747#5747) , [Is it possible to duplicate eyes?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/553/is-it-possible-to-duplicate-eyes)

Answer (score 2):

As it comes straight from the Naruto wikia:

[**Edo Tensei**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation)

[image: Summoning of the 4 Hokage]

> **The Summoning: Impure World Reincarnation** *binds the soul of a deceased
>   person to a living vessel, restoring them as they were when they were
>   alive in order to do their summoner's bidding.*

So that's why [Itachi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Itachi) had both of his eyes, because he was restored in the state before he died, which he had both of his [eyes](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan).

Comment: As shown with Madara, the State of the body can also be controlled. He was reincarnated in his young form, decades younger than when he died, as well as having been given a cloned Hashirama Face on his chest, but also had the reinnegan which he only obtained in his old age. His reanimated body was Mostly young but with some older and some custom aspects included. Nagato also seemed to be in better condition reanimated, able to walk and fight with his main body.